# Several azure functions in the same file. Do the non-relevant dependencies get deployed for other functions as well?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

Here is how my Functions file looks like with several Azure functions in it:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql;
using Core.Entities.SqlServer;
using ReplicaService.TriggerProcessors;
using CoreConstants = Core.Constants;
using Timelock.Core.Entities.SqlServer;
using Timelock.ReplicaService.TriggerProcessors;

namespace TriggerFunctions
{
    public class TriggerFunctions
    {
        private readonly UserChangeProcessor _altUserChangeProcessor;
        private readonly UserContractFieldChangeProcessor _altUserContractFieldChangeProcessor;
        private readonly PilotAgencyChangeProcessor _altPilotAgencyChangeProcessor;
        private readonly AgencyRuleChangeProcessor _altAgencyRuleChangeProcessor;
        private readonly AgencyFlagChangeProcessor _agencyFlagChangeProcessor;
        private readonly AlternateCalendarChangeProcessor _altAlternateCalendarChangeProcessor;

        public TriggerFunctions(
            UserChangeProcessor altUserChangeProcessor,
            UserContractFieldChangeProcessor altUserContractFieldChangeProcessor,
            PilotAgencyChangeProcessor altPilotAgencyChangeProcessor,
            AgencyRuleChangeProcessor altAgencyRuleChangeProcessor,
            AgencyFlagChangeProcessor agencyFlagChangeProcessor,
            AlternateCalendarChangeProcessor altAlternateCalendarChangeProcessor)
        {
            _altUserChangeProcessor = altUserChangeProcessor;
            _altUserContractFieldChangeProcessor = altUserContractFieldChangeProcessor;
            _altPilotAgencyChangeProcessor = altPilotAgencyChangeProcessor;
            _altAgencyRuleChangeProcessor = altAgencyRuleChangeProcessor;
            _agencyFlagChangeProcessor = agencyFlagChangeProcessor;
            _altAlternateCalendarChangeProcessor = altAlternateCalendarChangeProcessor;
        }

        [Function("UsersTrigger")]
        public async Task UsersTrigger([SqlTrigger("dbo.Users", CoreConstants.AppSettingsConnectionStringKey)] IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<UserEntity>> changes, FunctionContext context)
        {
            await _altUserChangeProcessor.ProcessChange(changes);
        }

        [Function("UserContractFieldsTrigger")]
        public async Task UserContractFieldsTrigger([SqlTrigger("dbo.UserContractFields", CoreConstants.AppSettingsConnectionStringKey)] IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<UserContractFieldEntity>> changes, FunctionContext context)
        {
            await _altUserContractFieldChangeProcessor.ProcessChange(changes);
        }

        [Function("AgencyFlagsTrigger")]
        public async Task AgencyFlagsTrigger([SqlTrigger("dbo.AgencyFlags", CoreConstants.AppSettingsConnectionStringKey)] IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<AgencyFlagEntity>> changes, FunctionContext context)
        {
            await _agencyFlagChangeProcessor.ProcessChange(changes);
        }

        [Function("PilotAgenciesTrigger")]
        public async Task PilotAgenciesTrigger([SqlTrigger("dbo.PilotAgencies", CoreConstants.AppSettingsConnectionStringKey)] IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<PilotAgencyEntity>> changes, FunctionContext context)
        {
            await _altPilotAgencyChangeProcessor.ProcessChange(changes);
        }

        [Function("AgencyRulesTrigger")]
        public async Task AgencyRulesTrigger([SqlTrigger("dbo.AgencyRules", CoreConstants.AppSettingsConnectionStringKey)] IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<AgencyRuleEntity>> changes, FunctionContext context)
        {
            await _altAgencyRuleChangeProcessor.ProcessChange(changes);
        }

        [Function("AlternateCalendarTrigger")]
        public async Task AlternateCalendarTrigger([SqlTrigger("dbo.AlternateCalendar", CoreConstants.AppSettingsConnectionStringKey)] IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<AlternateCalendarEntity>> changes, FunctionContext context)
        {
            await _altAlternateCalendarChangeProcessor.ProcessChange(changes);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the dependencies for each function are pretty much independent from each other.
So when I deploy these functions to the same Azure Function app, does each function only bring relevant dependencies or all of them?

The reason for my question is because I need fast scaling, and as each dependency brings quite a bit if extra code internally, I want to make sure that only relevant code per function is deployed for each function.

And if this is not the correct approach, what would the right approach be to insure independent dependencies between functions?

I am using Azure V4 isolated SQL Trigger Functions (not that I think it matters)

Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK in Azure Functions, when you have multiple functions within the same project or when you deploy multiple functions within the same Function App, the dependencies will be installed in project level.

Every function in the project will have access to all the dependencies.

[image]

All the dependencies for each function will be bundled and deployed together and all the functions runs within the same environment in the function app.

All the dependencies of every function of that particular project will be available as bundle in *.csproj* file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In your case:

- Though the dependencies for each function are independent of each other, every function will have access to all those dependencies, but the functions utilize its required dependencies at runtime.
- This allows Azure Functions to be more efficient as only the code for the triggered function will be executed when that particular function is called.
- All the deployed dependencies dll can be seen in KUDU site(Function app=>Advanced tools=>Kudu=>Debug=>CMD=>`site/wwwroot`):

[image]

- Azure Functions automatically scales out its resources based on the demand/requirement.
- When a function receives more requests, it will automatically add more instances of that function to manage/ handle the increased load.
- If you want to have *isolated set of dependencies* for each function, you need to consider deploying the functions *separately* to *different function apps*.

**References:**

[Azure Functions best practices | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices?tabs=csharp#organize-your-functions)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a thorough answer! This is exactly what I need.